# Environment for Applet development

Tags: graphing

I am interested in creating an applet to illustrate how polar graphs get formed.  I was able to make some videos of what I envision using *Interactive Physics.*

But they are not really interactive once the video is exported.  Still, you can see what I am aiming for here:  http://wp.me/p4uvY7-9V

If you were starting from scratch and you wanted to make this into a web-based applet where students could choose the function and change the parameters on the fly, how would you begin?  Is this something that I could do in Geogebra?  Do I need to learn to write Java code?

Thank you.

Comment: To create an Applet sensibly, you need to learn to write Java, yes. So far as I know, Geogebra cannot "export" to Java, although such a thing is not out of the question, in principle.

Comment: You can save a geogebra app on geogebra.org and then export as an iframe into any website. You can also host the app on geogebra tube, and organise your apps into books and chapters interspersed with text if you please. If this is useful, tell me and I'll expand the comment into a more detailed answer.